# Class SubList() must either be called abstract or implement abstract method 'listIterator' in 'List'

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij throws this error, but I am implementing it. This is a subclass of my main class MyList which is based off of ArrayList.

Class SubList() must either be called abstract or implement abstract method 'listIterator' in 'List'

```
private class SubList extends MyList<AnyType>
{
    private List<AnyType> original;
    private int offset;
    private int size;


    public MyList<AnyType> subList( int from, int to )
    {
        return new SubList( this, from, to );
    }

    public SubList( int from, int to )
    {  if( from < 0 || to > MyList.this.size( ) ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( from + " " + to + " " + MyList.this.size( ) );
        original = MyList.this; offset = from; size = to - from; }

    public SubList( SubList sub, int from, int to )
    { if( from < 0 || to > sub.size( ) ) throw new IllegalArgumentException( from + " " + to + " " + sub.size( ) );
        original = sub.original; offset = sub.offset + from; size = to - from; }

    public int size( )
    { return size; }

    public AnyType get( int idx )
    { return original.get( offset + idx ); }

    public AnyType set( int idx, AnyType x )
    { return original.set( offset + idx, x ); }

    public boolean add( AnyType x )
    { throw new UnsupportedOperationException( ); }

    public AnyType remove( int idx )
    { throw new UnsupportedOperationException( ); }

    public boolean remove( Object x )
    { throw new UnsupportedOperationException( ); }

    public boolean contains( Object x )
    { for( AnyType item : this ) if( item.equals( x ) ) return true; return false;  }


    public ListIterator<AnyType> listIterator( int idx )
    { return original.listIterator( offset + idx ); }

    public Iterator<AnyType> iterator( )
    { return original.listIterator( offset ); }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the signature of `public ListIterator<AnyType> listIterator( int idx )` in `MyList`? Is it identical?

Comment: There are two methods in `List`: `listIterator(int)` and `listIterator()`. We really need the code for `MyList` to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: And surprise, the two names in your comment do not match the two names in your source code. iterator() aint the same as listIterator() !

Comment: @Jägermeister: OP has a `listIterator` method as well.

Comment: @augray I don't see it in the `SubList` class. Now, it could be that it's overridden in `MyList`, but I doubt it.

Comment: The second to last method I see in the code is `public ListIterator<AnyType> listIterator( int idx ){ return original.listIterator( offset + idx ); }`. I'm assuming you must be talking about a method with signature 'ListIterator<AnyType> listIterator()', not shown but inferred since his `MyList` is based on `List`?

Comment: The point is: your compiler does not lie. Post the code of the interface too. Besides: if you add the `@Override` notation to those methods of which you **think** that they implement the interface ... the compiler will also tell you if there is a mistake (in case the corresponding method doesn't overwrite anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods in `List`: [`listIterator(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator-int-) and [`listIterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator--). You appear to be overriding the former, but not the latter.

Comment: This.  I added the method without the arguments and I was able to compile.